# GIT - checkout to branch name starts with '<' symbol

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

I've created a branch named  `<title>-changes` by:

`git checkout -b <title>-changes` and did a commit on that branch. Later I checkout to `another-branch` started working on `another-branch`. Now I want to checkout to the previous branch (`<title>-changes`) but I can't do that now through:

```
git checkout <title>-changes
```

I know this is a simple issue but can't crack. I tried:

```
git checkout \<title>-changes
git checkout /<title>-changes
git checkout '<title>-changes'
```

but no luck. Getting errors like:

```
$error: pathspec '<title' did not match any file(s) known to git.
$bash: title: No such file or directory
$error: pathspec '<title>-change-pdp ' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Comment: try `git checkout '<title>-changes' --`. A better solution is to avoid special characters in branch name.

Comment: Try using `git checkout -- <title>-changes`.

Comment: @pRaNaY: that's the opposite of what you want: after `--` are pathnames.

Comment: From the error, it seems what you tried was actually `'<title>-changes '`, with a space before `'`. Remove the space and it should work.

Comment: Yes. I had an extra space there in the name. removal of space worked. `git checkout '<title>-changes' --` worked too. But `git checkout -- <title>-changes` didn't, even-though doc had something like it. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to escape both `<` and `>` because bash treats them as special symbols.

In order to do that, prepend the backward slash `\` to each of them:

```
git checkout \<title\>-changes
```

This is what I did to test this, and it worked.

```
mkdir test
cd test/
git init
git branch \<title\>-changes
touch empty
git add empty
git commit -m "Added empty file"
git branch \<title\>-changes
git checkout \<title\>-changes
touch second
git add second
git commit -m "Added second empty file"
git checkout -b another-branch
touch third
git add third
git commit -m "Added third empty file"
git checkout \<title\>-changes
```

Comment: If you have to escape the `<` and `>` then how he could create the branch without escaping in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from **@Ferran Rigual**'s answer there is another solution. Like **@Matthieu Moy** said I had an extra space in the branch name. Removing it solved it too.ie,

I changed `git checkout '<title>-changes '` to `git checkout '<title>-changes'`

And for the record: `git checkout '<title>-changes' --` worked too. But I don't know `--` has any importance in the command since removal of it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: The `--`at the end of the line doesn't matter at all ;) It tells bash (the interpreter) not to expect any more parameters. Source: http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash